# Partial Load Pickle/Cloudpickle file without required modules and classes

Tags: python, pickle, dill

I am building an open source machine learning dashboard called [ML_Dash](https://ml-logger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setting_up.html#ml-dash-tutorial), which save training parameters in a pickle file to preserve arbitrary python objects that the user specifies. This is useful for loading the file back by the training client.

The dashboard however, provide introspection to the content of these `parameter.pkl` files and otherwise generic pickle blobs (think of a trajectory that you want to dump). The required python modules are more likely not present in the server's python environment. So I need a way to inspect cloudpickle'ed files without the require modules.

How do I partially load a pickle file without the required modules?

I tried to use pyCharm's debug mode to inspect where the error trace for a failed `cloudpickle` load is and monkey patch, but it seems the error trace does not include frames inside the `cloudpickle.load` function.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, we can use a custom `Unpickler` from the `pickle` module to accomplish this!

Full script below:

```py
from cloudpickle import dump
import pickle

def save():
    from uvpn.maze.uvpn_e2e import UVPN

    agent = UVPN(graph_n=100, buffer_n=100, latent_dim=10,
                 neighbor_r=1, neighbor_r_min=0)

    data = dict(title="agent object",
                count=0,
                nested=dict(value=list(range(100))),
                agent=agent)

    with open("agent.pkl", 'wb') as f:
        dump(data, f)

    print("done.")


def factory(module, name):

    class Lie:
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print(args, kwargs)
            self.__d = dict()

        def __setitem__(self, key, value):
            self.__d[key] = value

        def __getitem__(self, item):
            return self.__d[item]

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print(args, kwargs)

        def __repr__(self):
            return f"<class '{module}.{name}'>"

    return Lie

def read():
    from termcolor import cprint

    class Whatever(pickle.Unpickler):
        def find_class(self, module, name):
            try:
                return super().find_class(module, name)
            except:
                return factory(module, name)

    with open("agent.pkl", 'rb') as f:
        agent = Whatever(f).load()

    print(agent)
    cprint("success!", "green")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # save()
    read()
```